# Can a windows program on CD run on a portable DVD player

Tags: dvd

Is it possible to run on a portable DVD player a CD which has autorun feature installed and a windows program on it? The application to be run and its data are on the CD itself. The program is a windows exe file which needs supporting files which are also there on the CD. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, not if there is no Windows Operating System to run the program, you still need an Operating System.

Comment: Which operating system is there on portable DVD players? Will a linux program on CD work?

Comment: I have no idea what dvd player you have.

Comment: I am yet to buy one. Which portable DVD player can be used to autorun windows (or linux) programs on CD?

Comment: None that I know of, they are not computers, just disc (movie) players as far as I know.

Comment: They must be having some operating system and some program to load and run data on DVDs.

Comment: Its a single purpose OS, very small and only does a very few things.

Comment: Thanks for your time. One last question- are you aware of any good link on operating systems of portable DVDs?

Comment: No, sorry i do not.

Comment: @mso A laptop..

Comment: An OS is needed if you want to use the device for general-purpose computing.  It allows unknown software to use the hardware resources.  If the device is dedicated to a single purpose, it can have dedicated hardware and no OS is required.

Answer (score 4):

A CD/DVD player may contain sophisticated software for DRM and video/audio decoding, but is unlikely to contain a full-fledged operating system as Windows or Linux - unless it is something similar to a [TiVo](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=TiVo) (seems to be Linux based)

Simple devices can (apart from the mechanics) be anything from a couple electronic chips with embedded software and "up" in complexity. Expect the price of the device to be indicative of the complexity.

"FreeRTOS" might be the plausible software in the device:
http://www.freertos.org/

RTOS?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: What minimum operating system can be used to run a windows exe file on a CD? And is it possible to replace OS of a portable DVD player?

Comment: Answer to both of those: "Probably none", and "Unlikely".